# Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module" from gnome-system-monitor

Tags: 18.04, apt, gnome, gtk, system-monitor

i ran gnome-system-monitor from command line and i got this error

```
   Gtk-Message: 21:17:18.579: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

i tried

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk3-module
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module
sudo apt install canberra-gtk*
```

and i still got the same error

I am on ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS minimal install
Note that if i went to the search bar to find system monitor, bypassing the command line terminal, i can open the system monitor program

Comment: What is the issue? Is system monitor not loading?

Comment: @vanadium if i search it through the search bar, it works. But if i try to access it via the command line terminal gnome-system-terminal, it gives an error

Comment: To be clear, it gives an error and does not load?

Comment: @vanadium yes it gives an error and does not load if I do it via CLI

Comment: This is still not clear in your question. Use "edit" to clarify your question. Clear questions are more likely to attract clear and specific answers.